# Spark streaming recover from stoppage

Tags: apache-spark, real-time, apache-storm

I'm looking for a way to stream log data from files into our database. I've been reading about [Spark streaming](http://spark.apache.org/streaming/) and [Storm](https://storm.apache.org/) manage real-time but I don't know how to manage data non processed because an stoppage.

I mean, let say system is running and data is processed real-time, suddenly the system stops and restarts after 10 minutes. Is there a way to process this pending data without affecting the real-time stream ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example on `Storm` you need to read from a reliable data source, which holds the incoming messages and allow the consumer to continue from the point where it stopped. An example of such data source is `kafka`

In the case of [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/), the live stream will not stop because your consumers (storm, spark, or whatever you are using) stop. Kafka will continue receive messages and will keep supply them to the clients whom are subscribing to a particular stream.

**The key, for fault tolerance is on the system you choose to *distribute* your live stream, and not on the tools you choose to process it.** Your processing tools can always recover from the point where they stopped and continue the processing **as long the messaging system allows it**.

Another message system broker that can handle consumer failure is `Rabbit MQ`.

Comment: Thanks, Kafka was on my mind. What I'm looking for, sorry for not been clear before, is about how Spark or Storm can process streaming and batch data. After getting back there will be data stored that needs to be processed and it can be hours of data, but it can not affect the streaming process because I always need live data to be shown on the monitoring system.
Is there any way to ask Kafka to move a message to another topic if it was not consume after X seconds for example? In that way a can have a real time consumer and a batch one, right? Thanks in advace

Comment: @GBrian If you want to process batch data you need to copy it first to some place like hdfs (you can for example use Camus to copy data from data kafka to hdfs), and then process your batch (usually this means hadoop or spark). You can't run batch jobs over kafka. I have my kafka topics to hold 7 days, buts that's only to make sure if something goes wrong (for example Camus stops to work) I have 7 days to fix it, before the data is discarded...

Comment: @GBrian and not Spark Stream and Spark Batch are not the same thing. And Storm only does real time